# Creating a Table Model component using Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, tablemodel

I'm trying to create a custom table model, but I got stuck.

I want to create a table model and bind it using the Netbeans GUI. However, as you can see on the screenshot, the Component dropdown is inactive.

How can I create such a model component, and where do I put it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking columns and rows

Comment: I need it to be dynamic

Comment: Ahh. So use JTable#setModel, check out [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)